# How do I override a default value of a form?

Tags: django, overriding, default

Can someone help me here?

My form looks like this:

```
class RecieveLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    purchaseorderline = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    rl_quantity = forms.IntegerField(label='Quantity')
    class Meta:
        model = RecieveLine
```

Now, I need to set a default value for my purchaseorderline which is originally a ModelChoice, but I overridden it as IntegerField because I'm planning to hide it so that whenever I get its data, it will return an integer and not an Object. Anyway, I need to know how to override the default value of it. Must I use the `__init__`? My problem there is that, I don't know how to override the default value after it's been set. Any suggestions?
z

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set this in the declaration using the inital parameter:

```
class RecieveLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    purchaseorderline = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=37)
```

If you need to do it dynamically, then provide it as a dictionary when you create your form in the view:

```
initial_values = {'purchaseorderline': 37}
form = ReceiverLineForm(initial=initial_values)
```